# Installshield Excel Add-in

Tags: excel, add-in, installshield

I have created an excel add-in in VS2010. I am trying to create an installation using Installshield. I do not want to use the publish setup.exe that VS2010 will create. The reason is that I need to place certain files on the target computer and would like to do so using installsheild.

My issue is that I do now know what files should go where. Normally the installation does everything.

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you won't like my answer.

Some setup authoring tools offer direct support for Office add-ins. You configure some basic settings and build your project to get an installer.

Others don't offer support, so you need to do it manually. If you want to use this type of tool, you should find out what you need to install and where. Each add-in is unique and may have special requirements, special settings or use special locations.

If you want to configure the installer yourself, you first need to install your add-in manually and then try to replicate your actions in the installer. Automagical solutions are available only in setup authoring tools which support them.

Basically, you've got some learning to do about add-in deployment.

Comment: There's some good pointers on my blog from over the years. Google "vsto lessons learned".

Answer (score 1):

I am totally agree with *Cosmin Pirvu*, but it is not so tough in InstallShield to create Installer for Add-In.

It is not straight forward but I can give you a Tip which actually worked for me...
*The Basic Problem that People face is Registry Entries that Windows Installer creates secretly for you in case of Add-in installation.*

1. Create Add-In Setup using Windows Installer (by default you will get it with your solution).
2. Install Add-In test it and see whether it is loading perfectly or not.
3. Open InstallShield application (not in Visual Studio, open application directly).
4. Open your setup project file (.vbproj in case of VB.Net and .csproj in case of C#), Installshield will show you all the entries that you did in Windows Installer.
5. Open Installation Designer >> Goto **System Configuration** and and click on **Registry** Node, now in the right side lower panel **"Destination computer's Registry View"** right-click on **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** and click on **Export All** *This is the Trick* to create a Reg file.
6. Go to your solution and add InstallShield Basic Installer project to it, after adding it you can use Installshield Toolbar (If not use Installshield Menu) and select **Visual Studio Deployment Project Import Wizard**. Run it and convert your old Windows Project to Installshield project.
7. Once your project is ready go to the same registry node from where we have exported our registry file (see the description above) and this time click **"Import Reg File ..."**

Now you are ready to go .. rest of the things are easy..

I have searched it for many days and when I didn't find it anywhere on the internet I thought to post the solution here that I tried myself.

Comment: Don't do this. There is no reason to install every registry key on the dev machine on the target machine. This is why everyone's registries is a mess... Take the time to figure out which CSLDs you need and export just those to be installed.

Comment: The registry entries I am exporting are from the windows installer that I have created using MS Setup and Deployment Project. So all the entries that I am getting is from the same, and it will not messup the registries, as the registry entries exported are mapped to the specific component CLSIDs.